# Why I get the error-code 50 after trying to execute system(unzip) in PHP

Tags: php, file, system, unzip, error-code

I tried to unzip a file with `system('unzip file.zip', $return_val);` 
I get the Error-Code 50 if I execute the code: `echo $return_val`. 
Does somebody knows why? And how to fix it?

Comment: Is your disk full?

Answer (score 2):

Getting the error code 50 when unzipping a file typically means your disk is or was full during the extraction process. Please clear some disk space and try the operation again.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the man pages of `unzip`; exit code 50 refers to the disk being full during extraction .

[Reference](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip)